# When scrollbar appears, it pushes all content to left. How to instead make scrollbar appear to right of existing container?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

This is for a Chrome Extension I'm working on.

The scrollbar isn't coded into the HTML/CSS/Javascript anywhere in its present form. When enough elements get added to the Extension memory, and a button is clicked to reveal a user's saved items, the default browser scrollbar simply appears there.

When it does appear, it pushes all previously visible content left, shifting it all from its previous position, and it's pretty visually clunky and unattractive.

How could I instead make this scrollbar appear to the right of the pop-up div container -- with everything inside of there remaining in their original position?

Thanks!

Comment: Some StackOverflow solutions I tested keep everything in its original position -- yet the scrollbar appears on TOP of those elements, instead of appearing to the right of this container. This causes overlap of elements, it just doesn't look good for my purposes.

Comment: Please post the html and css

Comment: Also, please post a screenshot or two. Or link to a short video that demonstrates the problem. Sometimes, a picture is worth a thousand words. "Some StackOverflow solutions I tested" - Please edit your original question to include links to these solutions, so we know what you've already tried.